# SuiteScript 2.0 saveRecord function not working

Tags: javascript, suitescript2.0

I wanted to write a simple script that opens the link in a new tab when the user saves the record (custom entry form) with one of the fields `custentity_ns_lead_brand_lead_status` having a certain value.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/currentRecord'],
/**
 * @param{currentRecord} currentRecord
 */
function(currentRecord) {
    
   

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when record is saved.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if record is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function saveRecord(scriptContext) {
        var currentRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;
        let CurrentValue1=currentRecord.getValue('custentity_ns_lead_brand_lead_status');
        if(CurrentValue1 == 'C:1 - Closed - Won [B]'){
            window.open('https://4001251-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/common/entity/vendor.nl','_blank');
        }
    }

    return {
        
        saveRecord: saveRecord
    };
    
});
```

After deploying the script to the custom entry form, the "Save" button simply stops working, meaning that you cannot save the record.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: look into the browser's console (press F12) for errors. Something must be there